# Will any Shimano mountain bike shift cable set work with any Shimano mountain bike derailleurs and shifters?

Tags: shimano, gears, repair, shifter, derailleur-rear

(Forgive me if this question has been asked before - but I don't know if I'm searching with the correct keywords to find the answer...)

My rear derailleur cable is stuck hard into the side of its tube, meaning I can't shift gears. I want to replace it, but I'm a novice and I'm not sure exactly what replacement cable I need. The bike is a [Cube Analog 2014](https://www.chainreactioncycles.com/de/de/cube-analog-hardtail-29er-mountainbike-2014/rp-prod114105), with Shimano Altus SL-M370 Rapidfire Plus shifters and Shimano Deore RD-M592 SGS Shadow 9-speed rear derailleur. I found this [Shimano shift cable set](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Shimano-Spares-MTB-Gear-Cable/dp/B0050O89NQ/), but it seems like this is a generic kit. Would this work? Would I need to cut it to the right size for my bike, or are they always the same size?

Comment: Its been said in the answers, but you need proper cable cutters for this. Most home tool kits will have something that cuts, but nothing that's good enough for shifter (and brake) cables. First time I did this job I tried without the right tools, eventually I got the job done, but purchased the right tool soon afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That set would be ideal. Any Shimano compatible cable will work with your shifter.

I would suggest stainless steel cables (better than galvanised cables) because they will stay in nice condition, so operate well, for longer. After that, there are diminishing returns in value. Getting a complete kit like that one gives you all the little parts as well if you want to re-do the outers whole you’re having fun.

You’ll need to cut the cables (and outers) down to size to suit your bike. For this you’ll want to have or borrow a good quality pair of cable cutters, most cycle specific ones are excellent and a good investment. (Park Tool, Birzman, Pedros, etc etc).

Only cut the inner cable when you’ve finished installing the cables and indexing the gears. That way you can remove and re-thread the cable any time if you make a mistake anytime. You can even coil up the excess cable to test ride the bike before you trim it down. Finish the cut cable with a cable cap to make it longer lasting and less likely to stab your leg.

If you install new outer cables, follow some online instructional videos and do the neatest job you can to get the smoothest, easiest shifting result, patience pays off here.

Comment: Park Tool has a comprehensive video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xg5MrDgLhHI. A Dremel or similar with a cut-of grinding wheel can be used to cut housing without crushing it, but de-burring with a needle file is required afterwards.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the comprehensive answer! I think I can borrow some cutters so I can try this out once the kit arrives. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Yes it will. The important factor for compatibility is the head of the cable that sits inside which will be the same. The cables will be significantly longer than you will need, so you'll have to cut them down to size. Use the old cable housing to determine the length of housing that you need (provided that it's been working well at the current length). Then thread the inner cable through to the derailleur and adjust your cable tension, then cut off the excess cable.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. Good tip on using the old cable housing as a reference.